# search only in post titles in the wordpress to get title and id

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm an android developer. I made a php file on my host and I include `wp-blog-header.php` . I used this file as a web service.

In the my app, there is a search part and I get `term` as String and `category` as id of user and send them to my php file .

now, I would like to search in post titles and return titles and ids of what user want.

```
function customSearch($term,$category){
.
.
.

}
```

I used prepare functions to get posts like below function, but I cannot find any function to search only in post titles.

```
function getLastItems()
{



    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 5,
        'offset' => 0,
        'category' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );

    $mjson = array();


    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($recent['ID']), array(400,300) );
        $url_img = $thumb['0'];

        $marr = array(
            'id'=>$recent["ID"],
            'title'=>$recent["post_title"],
            'img'=>$url_img
        );

        array_push($mjson,$marr);

    }

    return  $mjson ;



}//end get last items
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand your search part, but your question about to search in only title , this answer will do for you.

> 1. Add filter to search only in title, before search.
> 2. Remove Filter after search.

if you want to search in title, just add below to args.

```
function search_by_title( $search, $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! empty( $search ) && ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['search_terms'] ) ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
        $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

        $search = array();

        foreach ( ( array ) $q['search_terms'] as $term )
            $search[] = $wpdb->prepare( "$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s", $n . $wpdb->esc_like( $term ) . $n );

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search[] = "$wpdb->posts.post_password = ''";

        $search = ' AND ' . implode( ' AND ', $search );
    }

    return $search;
}


$args = array(
    's' => 'search string',
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true);

add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_title', 10, 2 );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args, ARRAY_A);
remove_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_title', 500 );


foreach($recent_posts as $posts) {

    // your custom code here
}
```

Comment: 0k, plz give me a complete function ! because I'm confused.