# search only in post titles in the wordpress to get titles and ids

Tags: php, android, wordpress

I'm an android developer. I made a php file on my host and I include `wp-blog-header.php` . I used this file as a web service in the my application.

In the my app, there is a search part and I get `term` as String and `category` as id of user and send them to my php file .

now, I would like to search in post titles and return titles and ids of what user want.

```
function customSearch($term,$category){
.
. //To search by title and limit by category
.

}
```

I used prepare functions to get posts like below function, but I cannot find any function to search only in post titles.

```
function getLastItems()
{



    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 5,
        'offset' => 0,
        'category' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );

    $mjson = array();


    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($recent['ID']), array(400,300) );
        $url_img = $thumb['0'];

        $marr = array(
            'id'=>$recent["ID"],
            'title'=>$recent["post_title"],
            'img'=>$url_img
        );

        array_push($mjson,$marr);

    }

    return  $mjson ;



}//end get last items
```

Comment: i have already given you answer in your old post , look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904585/search-only-in-post-titles-in-the-wordpress-to-get-title-and-id/31904911#31904911