# Autocomplete search by title and SKU

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Edit:

If I add the code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31904911/21533506 it only searches in the product titles:

```
   function search_by_title( $search, $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! empty( $search ) && ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['search_terms'] ) ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
        $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

        $search = array();

        foreach ( ( array ) $q['search_terms'] as $term )
            $search[] = $wpdb->prepare( "$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s", $n . $wpdb->esc_like( $term ) . $n );

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search[] = "$wpdb->posts.post_password = ''";

        $search = ' AND ' . implode( ' AND ', $search );
    }

    return $search;
}


$args = array(
    's' => 'search string',
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true);

add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_title', 10, 2 );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args, ARRAY_A);
remove_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_title', 500 );


foreach($recent_posts as $posts) {

    // your custom code here
}
```

If I add the code from here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/412121 search by SKU:

```
    function search_by_sku( $search, $query_vars ) {
global $wpdb;
if(isset($query_vars->query['s']) && !empty($query_vars->query['s'])){
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_sku',
                'value' => $query_vars->query['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    if(empty($posts)) return $search;
    $get_post_ids = array();
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $get_post_ids[] = $post->ID;
    }
    if(sizeof( $get_post_ids ) > 0 ) {
            $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $get_post_ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
    }
}
return $search;
}
  add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_sku', 999, 2 );
```

If I add both, it only searches from the product titles.I tried to combine them, but I didn't manage to make them functional. Can you help me somehow?

Original:

Based on the code here https://awhitepixel.com/making-autocomplete-search-in-wordpress-with-code/, I have the following code:

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script('autocomplete-search', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/autocomplete.js', 
        ['jquery', 'jquery-ui-autocomplete'], null, true);
    wp_localize_script('autocomplete-search', 'AutocompleteSearch', [
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('autocompleteSearchNonce')
    ]);

    $wp_scripts = wp_scripts();
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css',
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/' . $wp_scripts->registered['jquery-ui-autocomplete']->ver . '/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css',
        false, null, false
    );
});

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_autocompleteSearch', 'awp_autocomplete_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_autocompleteSearch', 'awp_autocomplete_search');

function awp_autocomplete_search() {
    check_ajax_referer('autocompleteSearchNonce', 'security');

    $search_term = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['term']);
    if (!isset($search_term)) {
        echo json_encode([]);
        wp_die();
    }

    $suggestions = [];

    // Query for products
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' => $search_term,
    ];

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            global $product;

            $product_id = $product->get_id();
            $product_name = $product->get_name();
            $product_image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($product_id, 'thumbnail'); // Obține URL-ul imaginii produsului

            $suggestions[] = [
                'id' => $product_id,
                'label' => $product_name,
                'image' => $product_image_url, // Adaugă URL-ul imaginii produsului în array
                'link' => get_permalink($product_id),
            ];
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    echo json_encode($suggestions);
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_head','woocommerce_js');

function woocommerce_js() { 
    // break out of php ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('.woocommerce-product-search input[type="search"]').autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: AutocompleteSearch.ajax_url,
                        data: {
                            term: request.term,
                            action: 'autocompleteSearch',
                            security: AutocompleteSearch.ajax_nonce,
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            response(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    window.location.href = ui.item.link;
                },
            }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $('<li>')
                    .append('<div><img src="' + item.image + '" width="25" height="25" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">' + item.label + '</div>')
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
        });
    </script>
<?php 
}
```

It works fine, but... How can I make it search only in the product title and by SKU? Can you help me modify it?

My code also searches in the product description and does not search by SKU. I tried to modify it, but I could not make it functional. Can you help me solve the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your awp_autocomplete_search method to achieve

```
function awp_autocomplete_search() {
    check_ajax_referer('autocompleteSearchNonce', 'security');

    $search_term = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['term']);
    if (!isset($search_term)) {
        echo json_encode([]);
        wp_die();
    }

    $suggestions = [];

    // Custom WHERE clause to search in post_title and meta_value (for SKU)
    add_filter('posts_where', 'custom_posts_where', 10, 2);
    function custom_posts_where($where, $query) {
        global $wpdb;
        
        $search_term = $query->query_vars['s'];

        if (!empty($search_term)) {
            $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" OR {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '_sku' AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value LIKE %s", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($search_term) . '%');
        }

        return $where;
    }

    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' => $search_term,
        'meta_query' => [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                'key' => '_sku',
                'value' => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    remove_filter('posts_where', 'custom_posts_where', 10);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            global $product;

            $product_id = $product->get_id();
            $product_name = $product->get_name();
            $product_image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($product_id, 'thumbnail'); 

            $suggestions[] = [
                'id' => $product_id,
                'label' => $product_name,
                'image' => $product_image_url,
                'link' => get_permalink($product_id),
            ];
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    echo json_encode($suggestions);
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with your code.